# Algebra of sets in R

Tags: measure-theory

Show that $$F=\left\{ { A }_{ n }=\bigcup _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ ({ a }_{ i },{ b }_{ i }] } \quad :\quad n=1,2, \right\}$$ is an algebra
Sugestion Family F is a family of all finite unions of form $({ a },b]$

Comment: So, what did you try so far, or more precise which axioms have you already proved?

Comment: I only have the defintion of algebra!!

Comment: Right. Now you prove that this satisfies the definition.

Comment: that's my problem, I can not prove that R belong to F

Comment: Is it really an algebra? Does it contain $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @ByronByLima: That's a good question in that form, you should have included your doubt about $\Bbb R\in F$ in the question.

Comment: sorry but the problem is prove that F is an algebra

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not an algebra, provided that the letters $a_i,b_i$ denote real real numbers (and not $\pm\infty$).

Simply, $\Bbb R\notin F$ because all elements of $F$ has *finite* measure (length) while $\Bbb R$ has not.

(However, it is still a *ring of sets*, i.e. satisfies all other criteria: closed under finite unions and intersections and set difference.)